# Hierarchical modeling categorical variable interactions in PyMC3

Tags: pymc3

I'm attempting to use PyMC3 to implement a hierarchical model with categorical variables and their interactions. In R, the formula would take the form of something like:

```
y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2
```

However, on the tutorial https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/GLM-hierarchical/#partial-pooling-hierarchical-regression-aka-the-best-of-both-worlds they explicitly say that glm doesn't play nice with hierarchical modeling yet.

So how would I go about adding the x1:x2 term? Would it be a categorical variable with two categorical parents (x1 and x2)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just manually add the interaction term to your linear model. You would have to add 3 regression coefficients (betas) and one intercept. You can then estimate your y with a likelihood as follows:

```
y = pm.Normal('regression', 
               mu=intercept + beta_x1 * data_x1 + beta_x2 * data_x2 + beta_interaction * data_x1 * data_x2, 
               sd=sigma, 
               observed=data_y)
```

The parameters themselves can all have hyperpriors to build a hierarchical model.